# How to construct confidence interval for true variance

Tags: probability, statistics

I am wondering how I can approach the following:

Suppose there exists a game , which was originally designed to be such that $500 $points would be the mean score.

Suppose in a  past year the mean score for a game was $520$.

In a random sample of $20$ people, the distribution followed normal distribution and the sample mean was $495$ while the sample standard deviation was $69$.

Construct a $90%$ two sided confidence interval for the true variance $\sigma^2$ and for $\sigma$.

My issue is I am confused on which info I need and which I dont.

For example, do I use that $n=20$ sample information to do this?

Can someone help me out with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $X_1,\ldots,X_{20} \sim \text{i.i.d. } N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, so
$$
\frac{SS}{\sigma^2} = \frac 1 {\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^{20} (X_i - \bar X)^2 \sim\chi^2_{19} \quad \text{where } \bar X = \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_{20}}{20}.
$$
Suppose $\Pr(\chi^2_{19}>A) = 0.05 $ and $\Pr(\chi^2_{19}<B) = 0.05 $. Then
$$
\Pr\left( A < \frac{SS}{\sigma^2} < B \right) = 0.9.
$$
From
$$
A < \frac{SS}{\sigma^2} < B
$$
we get
$$
A\sigma^2 < SS < B\sigma^2.
$$
The first inequality implies $\sigma^2 < \dfrac{SS} A$ and the second implies $\dfrac{SS} B < \sigma^2$. Hence
$$
\Pr\left( \frac{SS} B < \sigma^2 < \frac{SS} A \right) = 0.9.
$$
(So we definitely used the fact that $n=20$.)

Comment: Thanks, but what about just for $\sigma$ ?

Comment: Is it just the same approach?

Comment: @Quality : We have $$ \Pr\left( \sqrt{\frac{SS} B} < \sigma < \sqrt{\frac{SS} A} \, \right) = 0.9 $$, so that's a confidence interval for $\sigma$, but I haven't looked at whether it's the shortest possible one. $\qquad$